# Count of Rows from a JOIN

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
{
SELECT tp.ProjectID, tp.ProjectName, tp.ProjectDescription, tp.Developer, 
       tp.Owner, tp.StartDate, tp.CloseDate, tp.ProjectStatus, tp.CompletionPct, 
       Count(tb.ProjectID) as 'NumberofBugs'
FROM tblBTProject tp
LEFT JOIN tblBTBugs tb ON tp.ProjectID = tb.ProjectID
GROUP BY tp.ProjectID, tp.ProjectName, tp.ProjectDescription, tp.Developer, 
         tp.Owner, tp.StartDate, tp.CloseDate, tp.ProjectStatus, tp.CompletionPct
}
```

Is there a better way to write this?
I am joining 2 tables (tblBTProject tp & tblBTBugs tb). where there are multiple ProjectID's in tblBTBugs tb and trying to return a column of the count of multiple project IDs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to get all distinct projects from tblBTBugs

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ProjectID)) FROM tblBTBugs
```

and this is how to get the number of every project in tblBTBugs

```
SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(ProjectID) 
FROM tblBTBugs
GROUP BY ProjectID
```

or if you want all the columns

```
SELECT * FROM tblBTBugs
WHERE ProjectID IN (SELECT ProjectID 
                    FROM (SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(ProjectID) 
                          FROM tblBTBugs
                          GROUP BY ProjectID))
```

Comment: And with the other columns?